# Flash builder 4.7 has which version of eclipse?

Tags: flash, flash-builder

I  want  to  have a J2EE  perspective  in  Flash Builder, how it is  possible? And also I want to run my Flash + Spring project built on Flash Builder to run on tomcat server.

Please provide me with some suggestions and solutions I am really stuck with it and not able to move forward.

Answer (score 2):

If you open the following file:

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\eclipse\.eclipseproduct
```

Then you can see the version of eclipse that Flash Builder was packaged with.

The contents are:

```
name=Eclipse Platform
id=org.eclipse.platform
version=3.7.0
```

Eclipse 3.7 is a Flavor of Eclipse Indigo, which you can see from this list of Eclipse "Older Versions"

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Older_Versions_Of_Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Flash Builder 4.7 is built on Eclipse Indigo.  I've not tried to install the J2EE plugins into FB, but I've worked the other way (add FB plugin to the Eclipse Jave EE bundle).

The details are in the FB 4.7 Release Notes (http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-builder/release-note/flash-builder-4-7-release-notes.html)

In the Flash Builder directory there is a utilities directory with the program Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 Plug-in Utility.  Run this to install into an existing Eclipse installation.

Unlike FB 4.6, FB 4.7 comes with 32-bit and 64-bit versions.  Make sure you install matching Eclipse and Flash Builder versions.