# Install flash builder 4.x plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, flash-builder

Hi I am planning to start on a project which I want to design using Flex and  develop using eclipse.
Is there a way to Install flash builder 4.x plugin in eclipse .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254949/flash-builder-4-7-has-which-version-of-eclipse

Comment: thank you..:)..  i searched b4 i posted. But couldnot find this link...